# Inequality of product of discrete cosines

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, fourier-analysis, enumerative-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

Let $k,a,b,c$ be odd positive integers. Consider the following inequality:
$$
\sum_{x,y \in [k]} \cos^a\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{k}\cdot x\bigg) \cdot \cos^b\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{k}\cdot y\bigg) \cdot \cos^c\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{k}\cdot (x+y)\bigg) \geq 1
$$
where $[k] = \{0,1,\ldots,k-1\}$.

I already proved this inequality with combinatorial methods (the original research question comes from Sidorenko's Conjecture), yet this is a quite "simple" inequality, and using simple combinatorial methods on harder inequalities of such kind doesn't seem to work.

Therefore, if anyone has an analysis or maybe even group representation approach which may prove that inequality, I would like to hear it.

**EDIT**: If one shows that for every $z\in[k]$ it holds that
$$
\cos(z)\sum_{x\in[k]} \cos^a\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{k}\cdot x\bigg)\cdot \cos^b\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{k}\cdot (z-x)\bigg) \geq 0
$$ then we are done. I checked this one numerically and it seems to hold. It reminds me convolution and I'm pretty sure im missing some simple tools here.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Clarification: if $k$ is even then the lower bound is $4$ and not $1$, I suspect that it is equivalent to the case when $k$ is odd.